# Laravel 4 - Developing & deploying web application for other users

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Although I'm new to Laravel 4, there has been one question on my mind since day one which I cannot seem to understand, nor find any information on.

My plan is to build an open source web application, which other users will be able to download and use on their own server.  Now my current way of working is:

- Install Laravel with composer
- Add packages to composer than I need for the application
- Start coding: editing files directly inside of app/ (global.php, routes, controllers, views, migrations etc).
- Keep all of my assets within /public/assets/

This works fine for me, and I have no problems with it.  However the question is:

How will I deploy the application to users if I build it this way? If they install Laravel via composer, all of the files within /app will be default (obviously), so how would I go about getting my edited + custom files into their install of Laravel?

Do I have to build the whole application as part of my own bundle? Or is there some kind of way composer can pacakge what I've done to solve this problem I can see happening?

I'm just throwing words out, if someone could explain and point me in the right direction that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chuck all your files on github. You dont need to include composer. People can download composer and run it from the install directory (or if they have it globally run it from there)

If you run a composer install with laravel 4 only, it will download all fresh. In your case you just have all the library's in place already. So for future updates you as a developer can easilly upgrade to a newer version. The "users" can simply say "git pull" to update their instance. You still need composer to do your initial install (db seed, post install steps etc)

At least that is my point of view. Just look at a simple laravel 4 bootstrap example https://github.com/andrew13/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site it also holds all the files.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, I assume this is how it'll work then, was wondering if I had to package my own app or something like that. Thanks